# Value of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of iTextSharp.text.IElement)'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having a problem with this code in the highlighted line(*); getting the error in the heading. Any help would be appreciated as I cant get the solution.

```
Dim htmlarraylist As New List(Of iTextSharp.text.IElement)
htmlarraylist = *HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StreamReader(tempFile), New StyleSheet())*
document.Open()

For Each element As iTextSharp.text.IElement In htmlarraylist
   document.Add(element)
Next

document.Close()
```

Comment: what is the signature of method HTMLWorker.ParseToList? if you are using .NET 4 you can use 'var' keyword and stop caring about the types;)

Comment: Try to change StreamReader to FileReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so it sounds like `ParseToList` returns a non-generic `ArrayList`. The simplest way of fixing that - assuming .NET 3.5 - is probably to use `Cast` and `ToList`:

```
Dim htmlarraylist As List(Of iTextSharp.text.IElement)
htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StreamReader(tempFile), _
                                       New StyleSheet()) _
                          .Cast(Of iTextSharp.text.IElement) _
                          .ToList
```

Note how I've also change the first statement so it no longer creates an instance of `List(Of T)` only to immediately throw it away.

That's assuming you *really* want it as a `List(Of T)`. If you don't mind it just been an `ArrayList`, you can just change the declaration:

```
Dim list As ArrayList = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StreamReader(tempFile), _
                                               New StyleSheet())
```

You're only iterating over it in the code you've shown, after all. (You could equally change the declaration to use `IEnumerable`.)

Answer (score 1):

Shorten your code to just

```
document.Open()  
For Each element As iTextSharp.text.IElement In HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StreamReader(tempFile), New StyleSheet())    
  document.Add(element) 
Next
document.Close()
```